# download box file in java

Tags: java, download, box-api

when I download the file it always throw this Exception:

org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 210846; received: 0

my code:

```
String fileid=attachment.getBoxfileid();
String sha1=attachment.getSha1();
String filename=attachment.getFilename();

final String clientid=ToolsUtils.getBOXcomConfig().get(ToolsUtils.CLIENTID);
final String clientsecret=ToolsUtils.getBOXcomConfig().get(ToolsUtils.CLIENTSECRET);
BoxOAuthToken authToken=this.boxuploadService.getTokenByClientId(clientid);
BoxClient boxClient=new BoxClient(clientid,clientsecret,null,null,new BoxConfigBuilder().build());
boxClient.authenticate(authToken);
boxClient.addOAuthRefreshListener(new OAuthRefreshListener() {

    @Override
    public void onRefresh(IAuthData authData) {
    boxuploadService.updateBoxAccessToken(clientid,authData.getAccessToken(),authData.getRefreshToken());
            }
    });
BoxDefaultRequestObject obj = new BoxDefaultRequestObject();
obj.getRequestExtras().setIfMatch(sha1);
DownloadFileRequest downloadFileRequest=new DownloadFileRequest(new     BoxConfigBuilder().build(), new BoxJSONParser(new BoxResourceHub()), fileid, obj);
out = response.getOutputStream();
InputStream inputStream=boxClient.getFilesManager().downloadFile(fileid, obj);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream" );
response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"" );

while((readCount = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
}

out.flush();
```

Comment: To solve this problem, I use DefaultHttpClient but I don't know the real reason for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the reading part went wrong, did you catch any exception when calling downloadFile(fildId, requestObject) ?

my code looks like below :

```
try {

    BoxDefaultRequestObject requestObject = new BoxDefaultRequestObject();

    inputStream = boxClient.getFilesManager().downloadFile(fileId,
            requestObject);

} catch (BoxRestException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (BoxServerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (AuthFatalFailureException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

you can check whether the InputStream object is correctly generated by this way.